# Regex for dot in any language

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to validate just the dot, but to work for any dots in any languages. I found \p{P} that works for all the punctuation, but i only need the dot from there, and I didn't manage to find any regex. For example in Chinese or Japanese is  。

Comment: Do you simply mean you want to match a dot, like `\\.`?

Comment: in chinese or japanese is: 。

Comment: You should tell us which languages.  Chinese has `。` as full stop.

Comment: @Cid Other languages may have different full stop characters.

Comment: If you know all the "dots" in all languages, then you can simply cite them all in your regular expression.

Comment: I need to match the dots from every language without cite them all. for now I just know that in Chinese and Japanese it's different.

Comment: You could [search unicode table](https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=PERIOD) for the phrase 'point' or 'period' and [create a regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) on that basis.

Comment: So you've found `\p{P}` which works for all punctuation, you only need the dot from there which is `\\.`, but you also want to match dots from every language? That's what `\p{P}` does then right?

Comment: What is the use-case?

Comment: @Mark yes, but \p{P} it doesn't have only dot, it has other characters also

Comment: Just put all of your desired dots in a character class like `[...]`.

Comment: Why are you doing this, are you wanting to split sentences?

Comment: `String language = this.getLocale().getLanguage(); String dotRegEx = "\\" + (language.equals("zh") || language.equals("ja") ? "。" : ".");`. [Ternary](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html) - If the Locale language is Chinese or Japanese then use the chinese/Japanese character for a dot (。) otherwise use a period (.).

Comment: Have a look at [Interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) for the unicode 'period' characters